# Objective-C decrypt AES 128 cbc hex string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, aes

I am developing an application for iPhone on Snow Leopard with Xcode 3.1 that receives from a restful web service an encrypted text in hexadecimal format with the algorithm AES 128-bit (CBC). The algorithm uses an initialization vector + secret key. How do I decrypt this text? Thanks to everyone for the tips that I will succeed in giving.

EDIT: 
I get response from REST Server in hex AND crypted format,I try with this code but i receive always bad param error. Can you help me to find the error? 
Is it possible that i firstly convert the string response into binary format?

```
      NSString *response = [request responseString];

      NSData *encryptedData = [response dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
      NSString *key  = @"32charlength";
      NSString *iv   = @"16charlength";  
      NSData *unencryptedData = NULL;
      size_t unencryptedLength = [unencryptedData length];
      CCCryptorStatus ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0, key, kCCKeySizeAES128, iv, [encryptedData bytes], [encryptedData length], unencryptedData, [encryptedData length], &unencryptedLength);     
      NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:unencryptedData length:unencryptedLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) risultato.text = @"SUCCESS";
      else if (ccStatus == kCCParamError) risultato.text =  @"BAD PARAM";
      else if (ccStatus == kCCBufferTooSmall) risultato.text =  @"BUFFER TOO SMALL";
      else if (ccStatus == kCCMemoryFailure) risultato.text =  @"MEMORY FAILURE";
      else if (ccStatus == kCCAlignmentError) risultato.text =  @"ALIGNMENT";
      else if (ccStatus == kCCDecodeError) risultato.text =  @"DECODE ERROR";
      else if (ccStatus == kCCUnimplemented)  risultato.text = @"UNIMPLEMENTED";
```

EDIT2:
this function return  BAD PARAM because haven't the right buffer size where allocate decrypted data. I edit the function in this working way:

```
      NSData *encryptedData = [response dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
      const void *key  = @"32charlength;
      uint8_t *iv      = @"16charlength";  
      char buffer[4*4096]; 
      memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
              size_t size = sizeof(buffer);
      CCCryptorStatus ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, 
                                         kCCAlgorithmAES128, 
                                         0, 
                                         key, 
                                         kCCKeySizeAES128, 
                                         iv, 
                                         [encryptedData bytes], 
                                         [encryptedData length], 
                                         buffer, 
                                         sizeof(buffer), 
                                         &size);
```

This function working for me.. thanks so much.

EDIT 23 MARCH------

Now the system work form me with 16 byte key size. Now i have a question, what i can do to implement 32 byte key size ? thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using the `CCCryptor` functions included in the `<CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>` header. Check `man CCCryptor` for the gory details, in your case it sounds like you can use a single call to `CCCrypt()` to decode the received data:

```
CCCryptorStatus
CCCrypt(CCOperation op, CCAlgorithm alg, CCOptions options, const void *key, size_t keyLength,
     const void *iv, const void *dataIn, size_t dataInLength, void *dataOut, size_t dataOutAvailable,
     size_t *dataOutMoved);
```

Assuming you have the data to be decrypted in `NSData *encryptedData` you could try something like:

```
char * key = "shouldbe16chars.";
NSUInteger dataLength = [encryptedData length];
uint8_t unencryptedData[dataLength + kCCKeySizeAES128];
size_t unencryptedLength;

CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0, key, kCCKeySizeAES128, NULL, [encryptedData bytes], dataLength, unencryptedData, dataLength, &unencryptedLength);
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:unencryptedData length:unencryptedLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is untested, make sure you check the return value of `CCCrypt` for errors. Check the header file for details, it is well documented.

Comment: i'm a newbie, how i can initialize the var? I try this:
NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",response];
CCOperation *op      = "decrypt";
CCAlgorithm *alg     = @"AES"; 
CCOptions   *options = NULL; 
const void  *key     = "xxxx";  
size_t *keyLength    = [key length];
const void *iv          = @"xxxxxxxx-x-xxxxx";  
size_t dataInLength     = [hex length];
void *dataOut           = response;  
size_t dataOutAvailable = 10000;  
size_t *dataOutMoved    = NULL;
CCCrypt(op, alg, options , key, keyLength, iv, hex, dataInLength, dataOut, dataOutAvailable , dataOutMoved);

Comment: this is a C level API, and you are mixing up object types and enums all over the place. i have added an example above. if you want to know what type of parameter should be given, just hold the Cmd key and click on the function name to go to the header file, and do the same on the parameter types to see the options.

Comment: now work with 16 byte key size. What i can do to use 32 byte key size?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but are you sure that is no hardware support? on the net i see this https://gist.github.com/838614 but i don't know if it is work for me..

Comment: I was being stupid and getting confused between block and key sizes. The AES algorithm always uses 128 bit block sizes, but varying key sizes, so all you need to do in fact is change `kCCKeySizeAES128` to `kCCKeySizeAES256` and provide a longer key obviously.