# objective c aes 128 encryption for a c# web service

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, aes, commoncrypto

So I'm trying to figure out how to make an objective c version of this as it's part of a wcf service security that was implemented. My main issue here is Idk where to begin as some articles/tutorials would automatically pad 0 in the beginning (not sure if that's their IV) like so:

(a couple of replies down)

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/60926-aesencryption-in-objective-c-and-php.html

compared to this which doesn't use any padding:

[Objective-C decrypt AES 128 cbc hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682118/objective-c-decrypt-aes-128-cbc-hex-string)

Anyway, this is how the wcf encrypts using AES 128. Any advice or nudge to the right direction is very much appreciated. Thanks!!!.

```
public class EncryptionAES128
    {
     static public string EncryptString(string inputString, string key)
            {
                string output = "";


                Rijndael encryption = new RijndaelManaged();

                try
                {
                    encryption.IV = GenerateIV();
                    encryption.Key = StringToByte(key);

                    ICryptoTransform encryptor = encryption.CreateEncryptor(encryption.Key, encryption.IV);

                    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                            {
                                swEncrypt.Write(inputString);
                            }

                            byte[] cipherText = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                            byte[] encrypted = new byte[cipherText.Length + encryption.IV.Length];

                            encryption.IV.CopyTo(encrypted, 0);
                            cipherText.CopyTo(encrypted, IV_LENGTH);

                            output = ByteToString(encrypted);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }


                return output;
```

}

Comment: What does your CommonCrypto code look like? You can set a padding in the CommonCrypt functions: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CCCrypt.3cc.html

Comment: hmm.. well it's the regular commoncrypto header. I gotta check when I get home later.

Comment: Would it make sense to use SSL and not implement your own crypto?

Comment: well the encryption on the web service are already set up I just need to recreate it on the iphone app. I think it's easier.

Comment: If I get you right, the encryption output of your Objective-C code does not match the encryption created by WCF. You should post the Objective-C code you have written, so we can tell you what part might make the difference.

Comment: well it's more like idk where to start cuz the two links that i posted have different approaches. i dont have any idea on which one i should be following.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I'm facing the same problem.