# Encrypting a string in PHP and decrypting it in Objective C

Tags: php, objective-c, encryption, aes, nsurlconnection

I have a large piece of text which I have encrypted using Rijndael 128 CBC mode and encoded using base64 in PHP (see code below). This data is posted onto a webpage which is then downloaded by my app:

```
<?php
    $keyT = "keyString";
    $key = md5($key);
    $key_size =  strlen($key);    
    $plaintext = "Text_Block";

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                             $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    # prepend the IV
    $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;

    # encode using base64
    $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);

    $data = $ciphertext_base64;
?>
```

Using `<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>` I have set up a protocol that downloads the encrypted and encoded data into `downloadData (NSMutableData). Then in the -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection I have:

```
     -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
          NSLog(@"Succesfully downloaded data! received %d bytes.", [downloadData length]);
          NSString *dataText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:dataText options:0];
          // Now lets say I have the key created in the php file:
          char void *key = @"key goes here";
          // This is where it stops for me, how do I extract the IV (which should be the first 16 characters) and how do I use this to decrypt the data?
    }
```

Comment: proved preposition is important. Do you mean "Encrypting string in php, Decrypting in Objective C" ?

Comment: check this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682118/objective-c-decrypt-aes-128-cbc-hex-string

Comment: With MCrypt, Rijndael-128 used with a 32-byte key is the equivalent of AES-256, so you wouldn't be able to decrypt the string whatever you do, until you use a proper key.

Comment: Thank you Narf I will change the size of my key. @Rapot, sorry I will keep that in mind next time.